# Can a ppa repository be added to /etc/apt/source.list?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

By `sudo add-apt-repository '<deb url codename component>'`, a repository is added to the /etc/apt/source.list file.

By `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<user>/<ppa-name>`, I saw that all the ppa repositories are added to /etc/apt/source.list.d dir:

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
ferramroberto-sopcast-precise.list
ferramroberto-sopcast-precise.list.save
google-talkplugin.list
google-talkplugin.list.save
kalakris-okular-precise.list
kalakris-okular-precise.list.save
linrunner-thinkpad-extras-precise.list
linrunner-thinkpad-extras-precise.list.save
precise-partner.list
precise-partner.list.save
staticfloat-julia-deps-precise.list
staticfloat-juliareleases-precise.list
staticfloat-juliareleases-precise.list.save
telepathy-ppa-precise.list
telepathy-ppa-precise.list.save
ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list
ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list.save
venerix-blug-precise.list
venerix-blug-precise.list.save
```

1. Can a ppa repositories be added to the end of /etc/apt/source.list file, instead?
2. Why are ppa repositories are treated differently from non-ppa ones?
3. Are there other non-ppa repositories treated similarly as ppa ones?
4. Will  `sudo add-apt-repository '<deb url codename component>'` add a ppa repository to /etc/apt/source.list, or to some files under /etc/apt/source.list.d?

Answer (score 12):

1. Yes, PPA's can be added to `/etc/apt/source.list`, in similar way to debian (deb) repositories.

   ```
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/<ppa-name>/ppa/ubuntu <release-code-name> main 
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/<ppa-name>/ppa/ubuntu <release-code-name> main
   ```

   An example for WineHq:
   [image: ppa debian repository link]
2. Thought just matter of keeping things somehow easily managed, leaving `/etc/apt/source.list` only for official release repositories. All additional repositories goes to `/etc/apt/source.list.d/`. Easy to:

   1. add (creating file then editing existing one, a partial solution to avoid duplicates too)
   2. remove (with parsing a `/etc/apt/source.list` looking to related line)
   3. backup/restore (using compressed archive of `/etc/apt/source.list.d/` folder)
   4. avoid breaking things with much edits targeting `/etc/apt/source.list`
3. PPA are always added to `/etc/apt/source.list.d/` folder if wrote it in `ppa:<user>/<ppa-name>` form.

   *Reference:* `man add-apt-repository`

   ```
   REPOSITORY STRING
          REPOSITORY can  be  either  a  line  that  can  be  added  directly  to
          sources.list(5),  in the form ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> for adding Personal
          Package Archives, or a distribution component to enable.

          In  the   first   form,   REPOSITORY   will   just   be   appended   to
          /etc/apt/sources.list.

          In  the second form, ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> will be expanded to the full
          deb  line  of  the  PPA  and   added   into   a   new   file   in   the
          /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  directory.   The  GPG public key of the newly
          added PPA will also be downloaded and added to apt's keyring.

          In the third form, the given distribution component will be enabled for
          all sources.
   ```
4. Well, it seems only PPA's as shortcut goes to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. `add-apt-repository` or `apt-add-repository` is a Ubuntu specific tool. All I can think of is just Ubuntu decision to keep personal PPA's out.

   However you can modify it to use only `/etc/apt/sources.list`. It's a python3 script. Modify `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` line:

   ```
   shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
   ```

   replace it with this one below to resolve ppa shortcut form to a deb line form:

   ```
   shortcut = shortcut_handler(shortcut_handler(line).expand(sp.distro.codename)[0])
   ```

Comment: Note that, strangely enough, non-PPA repos will get added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @saiarcot895, I think `add-apt-repository` was written to ease the work with PPA in 1st place. Here the commit description when it was added: "*new helper script "add-apt-repository" that can be used to enable a repository from the commandline. Useful for e.g.'add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-desktop'*". https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/software-properties/main/revision/563